# How to simplify the definition of a templated callback function?

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I wrote a templated `Matrix` structure that abstracts continuous indexes internally by using maps.

```
Matrix<TCell, TKey> m;
```

There is a function to expand the structure, and I want to give the user the ability to pass a function pointer (`initFunc`) that fills newly created cells.

```
   void ExpandMatrix( Matrix<TCell, TKey>* matrix, 
                      std::set<TKey>* keys_c, 
                      std::set<TKey>* keys_r, 
                      ??? /*Function pointer to callback function */ 
                     )
```

Now my problem is, that this user-supplied function needs to be passed a pointer to, and the keys, of the cell, not any internal counter I use. And these are defined to be `TCell` and `TKey` via the template. So I cannot use this because it is not yet known what exactly `TCell` or `TKey` are:

```
typedef void (*initFunc)(TCell* pCell, TKey key_c, TKey key_r)
```

As far as my research goes, it is not possible to template a function pointer:

```
template<typename TCell, typename TKey> 
typedef void (*initFunc)(TCell* pCell, TKey key_c, TKey key_r)
```

What I currently do is to wrap the function in a class which the user is thought to derive, but that is cumbersome for the user. Isn't there a better solution?

```
template <typename TCell, typename TKey>
class DefaultCellInitializer
{
    public:
    virtual void Initialize(TCell* t, TKey key_c, TKey key_r)
    {
        return;
    }
};

template<typename TCell, typename TKey>
void ExpandMatrix(  Matrix<TCell, TKey>* matrix, 
                    std::set<TKey>* keys_c, 
                    std::set<TKey>* keys_r, 
                    CellInitializer<TCell, TKey> initializer = DefaultCellInitializer)
```

Note: I need to allow for a default value that does nothing to cope with legacy usage of the method. C++11 is welcome, but it has to be compiled on MSVC 2012. Boost is not (yet) an option, because of politics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `typedef` a template function pointer. You could define the parameter type of `ExpandMatrix()` as  a function pointer directly:

```
template<typename TCell, typename TKey>
void ExpandMatrix(Matrix<TCell, TKey>* matrix, 
                  void (*initFunc)(TCell*, TKey, TKey) = defaultCellInitializer) {}
```

and `defaultCellInitializer()` might be

```
template<typename TCell, typename TKey>
void defaultCellInitializer(TCell* pCell, TKey key_c, TKey key_r) {
    ... ...
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/RYUA75530)

Comment: Alright, I am so used to having function pointers defined outside with typedef's  that this never came to my mind. Gonna try it, seems promising

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `std::function` using those template types. This can be bound to a lambda.

```
template <typename TCell, typename TKey>
void ExpandMatrix( Matrix<TCell, TKey>* matrix, 
                  std::set<TKey>* keys_c, 
                  std::set<TKey>* keys_r, 
                  std::function<void(TCell*, TKey, TKey)> callback
                 );
```

Then the lambda:

```
ExpandMatrix(/* args */, []( /* type list for arguments */ ) {
  /* implementation */
  });
```

When you bind the lambda to the `std::function`, you will need to provide the types in the list of arguments required.

If you not limited to the lambda, you can use a function pointer as well.

Further, the `std::function` could be replaced with a template argument of its own and used in the same way the standard library uses predicates in its algorithms etc. (e.g. `std::find_if`);

```
template <typename TCell, typename TKey, typename Callback>
void ExpandMatrix( Matrix<TCell, TKey>* matrix, 
                  std::set<TKey>* keys_c, 
                  std::set<TKey>* keys_r, 
                  Callback callback
                 );
```

Again, the `callback` can be bound to function pointers, functors, lambdas etc.

Comment: Seems promising as well, but I would prefer simple function pointers because of the overhead of std::function. If @songyuanyao's suggestion does not bring success, I'm gonna go your route.

Comment: The overhead should be small, but is there. You could just make it a template argument itself, in the same way the standard library uses predicates etc in the standard algorithms such as `find_if` etc.

Comment: I did not want to discredit your suggestion with that statement.